# How can I responsively align items on bottom of a sidenav in BS5?

Tags: html, css, frontend, position, bootstrap-5

I want to responsively align items on the bottom of a sidenav, made using Bootstrap 5. I incorporated an example of a sidebar from the official Bootstrap Examples, and the `.offcanvas` class.

In the example, there was a dropdown next to a user profile where the user can access a ton of settings –– aligned at the bottom of the sidebar. However, that just wouldn’t work for me in my version of the offcanvas sidebar. I have tried a multitude of ways, but none of them have worked responsively.

Below is my code, not first and foremost, but at a decent introductory point in this question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>BS5 Offcanvas Sidenav</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.5.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
         .dropup {
         position: absolute;
         bottom:0;
         padding-bottom:2vh;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <main>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark d-md-none d-lg-none" aria-label="Dark offcanvas navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Side Nav</a>
               <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbarDark" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbarDark">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
               </button>
               <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start text-bg-dark flex-column d-flex" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbarDark" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarDarkLabel" style="min-width:160px;max-width:210px">
                  <div class="offcanvas-header">
                     <span class="fs-4">Offcanvas</span>
                     <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-bg-dark offcanvas-body" style="height:100%">
                     <hr>
                     <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
                           Home
                           </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                           Option A
                           </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                           Option B
                           </a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow">
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B. 1</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B. 2</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B. 3</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B. 4</a></li>
                              <li>
                                 <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                              </li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B. 5</a></li>
                              <li>
                                 <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                              </li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B. 6</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                           Option C
                           </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                           Option D
                           </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                           Option E
                           </a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <hr class="mt-auto">
                        <div class="dropup">
                           <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                           <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/0" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2">
                           <strong>Jippy</strong>
                           </a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow">
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New Project...</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                              <li>
                                 <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                              </li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                           </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="bg-light mx-auto">
               <h1 class="display-5 fw-normal">Navbar with offcanvas</h1>
               <p class="fs-5">This is a navbar that uses the <code>.offcanvas</code> Bootstrap class to work. I used a simple sidebar template from the official Bootstrap Examples along with the offcanvas class to make this work. The sidebar only shows on smaller screens.</p>
               <p>However, I am facing a <b>problem</b>. The dropup that should be displayed at the bottom of the sidebar? It is made using <code>position: absolute</code>, thus it starts to overlay on top of the other sidebar components if the vertical height is too small. However, I can't figure out how else to put the dropup at the bottom, which is the core of my problem.</p>
               <p>Sure, one could think that no one will probably ever go onto a website with a screen height of less than 400px, but with the age of smartwatches, I'm not too sure about that. So, I want to make this responsive. How can I do that?
               <p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com" role="button">Made using Bootstrap 5.2.3</a>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see above, I have incorporated some styling to try to get what I want to happen.

```
<style>
 .dropup {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  padding-bottom:2vh;
 }
```

This works decently well, but does not work correctly on smaller screens.

I have some images to show to explain what’s wrong.

[This image shows what the positioning of the dropup is on a standard phone, and I have no complaints here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nEwx.jpg)

However...

[When the screen height gets below 400px, the dropup continues to stay at the bottom of the sidenav, causing it to overlay on the other items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9xZy.png)

EDIT: I don’t have enough reputation to post the images directly, so please follow the links StackOverflow generated.

Answer (score 1):

Citizen
Try using The code Below after changing class names

```
 @media screen and ( max-height: 400px ) { 
 .logo{
   reduce font size of text menu e.g- font-size:12px;
   reduce height and width of image e.g- width: 100px; height:30px;
   reduce top/bottom padding and margin e-g - margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;
 }
 .search{
   reduce font size of menu items
   reduce gap between menu items
 }
 .main-menu{
   reduce font size of menu items
   reduce gap between menu items
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Kamal Joshi I managed to fix it by specifying a max height (inspired by your idea) and then not displaying the dropup at the bottom, instead, setting the display of a dropdown at the breakpoint not in an absolute position to `display:block`.